# Problems with binding to service in Android

Tags: android, binding, android-service

I have created a service, called LocalService, and I want to bind to it so that it can perform some action and give the result back to the calling client. I've been trying to get the [example of the android dev site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to work but eclipse gives a compile time error on this method:

```
void doBindService() {
    // Establish a connection with the service. We use an explicit
    // class name because we want a specific service implementation that
    // we know will be running in our own process (and thus won't be
    // supporting component replacement by other applications).
    bindService(new Intent(Binding.this, LocalService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}
```

There is a red line under "Binding.this" and eclipse gives me: Binding cannot be resolved to a type. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove Binding, code should look like this:

```
bindService(new Intent(this, LocalService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

First parameter of `Intent` constructor is [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). Code above will work if you calling it from your Activity class (any instance of Activity is a Context also). If not, you can always use application context

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Binding` is simply class name you put `doBindService()` in (most likely Activity?). If your class is named otherwise either rename it to `Binding` or replace all `Binding.this` with `MyClass.this` or just `this`.